# Calculate number of options with no repetitions

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Given the word "REPETITIVENESS" calculate the number of words that does not include the series "SITE" OR "TERSE"

For example:
REPETIV**SITE**ENS is not valid
REPETITIVENESS is valid

I tried to count each letter:

R-1
E-4
P-1
T-2
I-2
V-1
N-1
S-2

and so the total permutations are: $\frac{14!}{4! \cdot 2! \cdot 2! \cdot 2!} = 454053600 $ and then use the include exclude theorem {permutations of words including SITE} and {perm. of words including TERSE}

but it seems incorrect... I don't know how to solve it I would like your help. Thank you!!

Comment: These are all words that use *all* the letters?

Comment: Permutations that include SITE and TERSE can include the words separately, or as “SITERSE.”

Comment: @ThomasAndrews together SITE TERSE\ and use all the words.

Comment: @StackOMeow Do you know the answer?

Comment: @RobertZ no... unfortunately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We already know the number of total arrangements,
$$\frac{14!}{4! \cdot 2! \cdot 2! \cdot 2!}=\frac{14!}{4! 8}.$$
The number of words including TERSE is
$$10\cdot\frac{9!}{2!2!}=\frac{10!}{4}.$$
The number of words including SITE (at least one time) is
$$11\cdot\frac{10!}{3!}-\binom{6+2}{2}\cdot\frac{6!}{2!}=
\frac{11!}{6}-\frac{8!}{4}.
$$
The number of words including SITE and TERSE as distinct words is
$$2\cdot \binom{5+2}{2}\cdot 5!=7!.$$
The number of words including SITERSE is
$$8\cdot \frac{7!}{2!}=\frac{8!}{2}.$$
Hence, by the inclusion-exclusion principle, we find
$$\frac{14!}{4! 8}-\frac{10!}{4}-\frac{11!}{6}+\frac{8!}{4}+7!+\frac{8!}{2}=446528880.$$

Comment: is it just the sum of what you wrote here?

Comment: You are going to use the inclusion-exclusion principle, aren't you?

Comment: Somewhere in the solution however I can't find where to use it here :( the repetition of SITESITE is like twice SITE so we need to exclude but how do I do it? I am confused

Comment: SITE should be $11\cdot\frac{10!}{3!}-\binom{6+2}{2}\cdot\frac{6!}{2!}$ or $\frac{11!}{3!}-\frac{8!}{2!2!}$

Comment: @DanielMathias You are right! Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @StackOMeow Any further doubt?

Comment: @RobertZ I am not sure at all :(

Comment: Ok I've read your answer again, I get it now. thank you!!